# Xcode build fails to generate an .ipa on mac m2 with generic react error message without documentation

Tags: reactjs, xcode, react-native, profiler, ipa

Xcode build fails to generate an .ipa on mac m2 with the following error message:

node_modules/react-native/React/Profiler/RCT Profiler Trampoline-x86_64.S unable to make temporary file: No such file or directory

where can we learn more about RCT Profiler Trampoline-x86_64.S?